# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing

Tags: mockito, powermockito

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:67)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:105)
    at us.ny.state.ij.safeact.ask.facade.AmmoSellerKeeperFacadeBeanTest.setUp(FacadeBeanTest.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at
```

**Code to mock**

```java
BusinessServiceFactory serviceFactory = BusinessServiceFactory.getInstance();
RegBusinessServiceImpl regCreateService = 
    serviceFactory.getRegBusinessService(adrEntityManager);
```

**Test Code**

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ BusinessServiceFactory.class})
public class FacadeBeanTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl  mockRegBusinessServiceImpl 
            = mock(AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(mockRegBusinessServiceImpl)
            .when(BusinessServiceFactory.class,"getRegBusinessService",
            (mockEntityManager)); //--- line 84 null pointer exception
    }
}
```

I can't understand why I'm seeing the exception. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: is this problem fixed? I am having exactly the same problem.

Comment: I realized my mistake. I have posted the solution as a reply below.

Answer (score 5):

## FYI:

The solution is to use **PowerMockito.mock()** instead of **Mockito.mock()**

---

***you should be doing***

```java
AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl  mockRegBusinessServiceImpl 
        = PowerMockito.mock(AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl.class);
```

***instead of***

```java
AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl  mockRegBusinessServiceImpl 
            = mock(AmmoSellerRegBusinessServiceImpl.class);
// assuming your are using Mockito.mock()
// correct me if I am wrong
```

---

I also faced the same problem. This solution was the fix for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `Mockito.when()` for mocking methods that return a value. Also you need to use the `PowerMockito.mockStatic()` prior to mocking the methods of the static class.

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(BusinessServiceFactory.class);
// use Mockito to set up your expectation
Mockito.when(BusinessServiceFactory.getInstance())
    .thenReturn(mockRegBusinessServiceImpl);
Mockito.when(mockRegBusinessServiceImpl.getRegBusinessService())
    .thenReturn(mockEntityManager);
```

Take a look at the [PowerMock usage](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) here to get a better understanding.

Comment: Hi, I have a question at this link, could you explain it to me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389576/powermock-in-scala-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-getpackagename